# Why is Kinim so long?

Tags: mishna, tractate-kinnim

*Mishnayos maseches Kinim* can be reduced to a few rules. I think they're as follows (though it's been a while, so I may be messing some of these up).

1. A bird *ola* is brought on the top of the *mizbeach*, and *chatas* on the bottom. Do either one wrong, and it's invalid.
2. A *chova* is one *chatas* and one *ola*; a *neder* or *n'dava* is two *olos*. If you bring more *olos* or *chataos* than that from a *ken*, the excess are invalid.
3. Both birds of a *ken* are *b'ne yona*, or both *torim*. If a mixed *ken* was brought, only the *chatas* is valid; *ben Azay* says only the first brought is.
4. If a bird may have been designated as a *chatas*, it cannot be brought as an *ola*; and vice versa.
5. If a bird can't be brought or was brought but is invalid, bring a new one in its stead, and its former mate is fine.

Why, then, does the *maseches* go on and on with examples instead of simply stating the rules? *Mishnayos*, from what I understand, are usually written to be easy to memorize. Surely *Kinim* as we have it is harder to memorize than the above.

Comment: Can't you make a nedava of only one bird?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if so, the _maseches_ doesn't discuss it.

Comment: Sure it does. In 3:6 it says (in a certain case) that she has to bring Od Preidah Achat which means one bird. You're thinking of if she was noder a kan which is two birds and is the first case in that mishna.

Comment: Also, I think you mixed up Tanna Kama and Ben Azai. See 2:5

Comment: @DoubleAA "_Od p'reda achas_" is not talking about someone who made a _n'dava_ of a single bird. And yes, I confused _ben Azay_ and the _t"k_: thanks! I've corrected it. (As I said, it's been a while....)

Comment: It's telling the women she must bring another bird. How will she bring it? She will nedava it misafek. This proves you could nedava it in general.

Comment: There are way more rules than this...

Answer (score 5):

While your summary might work for the general behavior of bringing sacrifices of birds in ideal situation, your summary does not cover, or give reference to the border cases, and what exactly is to be done with various birds or situations that can not be offered.

Also, at the point in time in which the mishna was written, these cases were not done in practice, so it seems that in these situations the Mishna is acting as it's own gemorah explaining as much as it can in as short a space as possible.  The rules as you have written them , might have allowed for expansion, but that expansion would have been lost due to a lack of familiarity and practice.  Just skimming through the mishnayot I see lots of information that is not covered in your short summary.

In addition, many people are able to learn extra idea and lessons from the Mishna which do not directly relate to the halachot as summerized. For example, you can learn some insights into childbirth and oaths from the mishnayot which one would not be able to learn from a summary of rules.

Comment: And how to make musical instruments out of an animal.

Comment: +1, especially for your second paragraph. (Much the same, after all, can be said of a good part of Taharos, especially Kelim - and probably for much the same reasons.)

Answer (score 4):

One significant rule you didn't mention is that if a bird from a group of "undesignated pairs" flies into another such group, it invalidates one bird in each group. Another important topic is the discussion at the end of the masechta regarding a kohen who didn't do what he was supposed to.

In any event, aside from the fact that there are more rules than the ones you mentioned, it should be noted that Mishnayos in general deal with practical, real-life cases rather than dry legal principles. For example, you will learn about the law when an ox gores a cow, or when two people fight over a tallis, rather than learning the bare rules that underlie those laws.

Comment: The two rules you mention in your first paragraph are just examples of the rules I give.

Comment: How so? Perhaps an offending bird can be botul b'rov. At the very least you would need to add another rule, that birds are not botul. This is actually one of the major "themes" that run through the masechta.

Comment: Fair enough. (But my point wasn't which rules there are, only that there are few.)

Comment: That's already 6 major rules, and there are many other details that haven't been mentioned. Remember that the entire masechta is only 3 chapters long!

Answer (score 1):

[Prof. Yaakov Epstein](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F) in his book "Introductions to the Tannaitic Literature", pg. 62, wrote on Kinim:

> "קינים היא כולה משנת ר' יהושע...ואמנם כל המסכת עם סדרה המיוחד, העמוק וההגיוני, ופירוט כל הפרטים והמקרים שאפשר להם להיקרות נושאת עליה חותם של ר' יהושע עם ספקותיו וספק ספקותיו (טהרות פ"ו מ"ב-מ"ו, עדויות פ"ב, מ"ז).

Translation: "Kinim is entirely the mishna of Rabbi Yehoshua...and indeed the whole tractate with its special, deep and logical organization and its describing of all of the details and cases that may possibly happen carries the signature of Rabbi Yehoshua with his uncertainties and compound uncertainties ([Taharot 6:2-6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Tahorot.6.2-6?lang=bi), [Eduyot 2:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Eduyot.2.7?lang=bi)).

In other words, Rebbi inserted into the Shas this masechet of Rabbi Yehoshua almost as it was given over by Rabbi Yehoshua, with hardly any later edits (Epstein notes the very few additions made by later tannaim). It was Rabbi Yehoshua's studying style to look over all possible hypothetical situations, hence the length and the many variant cases presented.

[Rabbi Reuven Margolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuvein_Margolies) [noted](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32665&st=&pgnum=51) it was important to Rebbi to preserve as much of the original language and style of the older mishnayot as possible.

Comment: Because R' Yehoshua is mentioned in two mishnayos with sefeikos, all such mishnayos are now his? This is another example of why I can't stand academic theorizing in general.

Comment: @N.T. note the three dots I put in the middle. I didn't quote everything Epstein brought. The sources from Taharot and Eduyot are not the proofs that the mishna is his. They're just other examples of his limud style.

Comment: @N.T. It may also interest you to know that Prof. Epstein was referred to by Rabbi A.I. Kook as "הכי גדול שבלמדנות" (ליקוטי הראי"ה ג, pg. 168). This was noted in the book as being one of only two out of ordinary titles used by Rabbi Kook to refer to friends of his (the other was ידיד נפשי, referring to Rabbi Prof. Shmuel Klein).

Comment: (I'm not really a Rav Kook fan, but) My main problem with academics isn't that they aren't smart or knowledgeable; it's the complete lack of intellectual rigor to their writings. Mountains of conclusions are made from molehills of observations.

Comment: It's not about being a Rav Kook fan. It's simply appreciating what a past gadol said about someone he apparently knew personally. Yes, Rav Kook was very polite and respectful toward practically everyone, but if he thought he was the sort who made mountains out of molehills, as you put it, he probably would not have regarded him in this manner. As for intellectual rigor - well, it depends who you look at. Prof. Epstein and Rabbi Prof. Klein knew Shas and midrash like the back of their hands.

Comment: Their conclusions usually stem from picking out tiny details in sources that can be connected with tiny details in other sources and out together like a puzzle.

Comment: I just don't think their conclusions are warranted by the size of the tiny pieces. We can agree to disagree.